# shell programming Syntax Error unexpected word, `$ '\ r''

Tags: shell, cygwin, sh

I am using cygwin for shell programming and this is my first program and i can't understand the error mentioned in the title at line 4 in for loop.here is the code

```
ski=0
wski=1
rwski=950435
for (( i = 1; i < 77; i++ ))
do  
    if [ $i -lt 45] ; then
        dd if=3d.jpg ibs=1024 count=1 skip=$ski of=myimage.dd obs=1024 seek=$wski conv=notrunc  
            expr $ski = $i
        expr $wski = $wski + $i
    else
        expr $rwski = $rwski - $i
        expr $ski = $i
        dd if=3d.jpg ibs=1024 count=1 skip=$ski of=myimage.dd obs=1024 seek=$rwski conv=notrunc
    fi
done
```

can someone please help me to correct this.

regards,

w

Comment: enable debuggin in youre script by changing the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x` or do a `set -vx` at the top of your script. Then watch the output and verify that everything is expanded as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a space after `45`, `]` is an argument for the function `[`.

but your problem is probably mixed dos/unix line endings, fix it with a proper editor or use `dos2unix`.